# How to create the android spinner listpopupwindows?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Hi I'm Developing android app, The app wants to show the spinner list like time zone (IST, PST, EST..etc) normally the spinner shows the dialog option, But i need to show the spinner like dropdown list, So Please tell me the solution in this issue.

Comment: Post your code. try adding this attribute in your spinner
android:spinnerMode="dropdown"

Comment: Cool Mark the answer accepted and close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this attribute in your spinner

```
android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
```